# How to add data attribute to html tag in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My question is in the title. I want to add a data attribute to `<html>` in vue.js (v2).
The auto generated code does not provide any hint to do so neither do the docs, as far as I see.

The desired result should look like:

```html
<html data-foo="bar">
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <!-- .. -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me how to accomplish this?

Comment: well, just put it there in your markup, or in code ... vue doesn't touch anything outside the root element (the id=app in this case) how would you do it if you were not using vue?

Comment: Now I feel stupid. Thanks! In my case there is the /public/index.html which will be used to inject the vue.js code.

Comment: you've learned something - think positive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this will works:

```
document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-foo', 'bar')
```

ps: I use this line to change my theme from dark to light mode. I got this from this [example](https://dev.to/ananyaneogi/create-a-dark-light-mode-switch-with-css-variables-34l8).